# match numbers not prefixed with specific word by Regex

Tags: regex

I want to extract the numbers that are not behind "A" by Regex.

For `textA123text`, none should be matched because `123` is behind `A`.

For  `textBC123text`, `123` should be matched.

I found negative lookbehind like `(?<!A)(\d)` does not work. It matches `23` in `textA123text` because `23` is behind `1`.

Is there any way to do this by using Regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to using negative lookbehind for `A`, also negative lookbehind for `\d`, to ensure that you're at the first character in a number, which is not preceeded by `A`:

```
(?<![A\d])\d+
```

https://regex101.com/r/jhWM30/1

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just add `\d` to your look-behind assertion:

```
(?<![A\d])(\d+)
```